# Symfony2 :Showing div content in the same page without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I work on a Symfony2 project and I am a beginner,

I have a problem (that i have idea about the solution)
I have a form that allowd me to add a review on something, it has many reviews shown at the bottom of its informations.

My goal is when I click the *Publish*-button, my review will be shown after the form and before the other reviews:

**Before the click:**
[image: Review form with existing comment below]

**After the click:** My review will appear with small animation
[image: Collapsed form with new comment on top of list]

PS: I have used this [Snippet](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/expanding-review-and-rating-box)

Any Help or idea please?
Thank you.

Comment: could you please provide some code which you have tried so far

Comment: For a more detailed answer we need to have a look at the JS which adds the review to the list, but basically. You want to [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) the review to the list of existing ones

Comment: this is my problem , i have any  idea to start with this :(